# Java Selenium, storing updated page source after javascript activation

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, web-crawler

I have managed to open a browser with my link and activate the javascript, which allows the page to display more results. Once this is done I am trying to print the new updated page source in the console but all it shows is the original source prior to the javascript activation. My code so far is shown below.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("www.desiredLink.com"); 

if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) 
{
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("javascriptFunction();");
    System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
} 
else 
{
    throw new IllegalStateException("No support for JavaScript!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get attribute "innerHTML" of body instead of pageSource:

```
String bodyHtml = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```